# Is there a good way to view my candidate score?

Tags: support, election

I notice the election candidates all have "candidate scores".
I don't want to be a moderator, but I do want to view my candidate score. Is there a way to view this without being a candidate?

If I self-nominate, will there be a way to un-self-nominate after viewing my score?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Data.StackExchange.com has a lot of very useful tools for doing things like this.

[This meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253781/154443) has the general calculation and query, but for a specific one for RPG you can use [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/query/298418/candidate-score) and all you need is your user id which can be found in your profile link (for example mine is 33161).

Your score using this query would be 24 out of 40.

Comment: Notably, there's no in-site feature for this, so SEDE is the only way (short of self-nominating).

Comment: The query you linked is accurate for me, it returns 39 out of 40, which is consistent with my nomination post.

Comment: It just returned 34, and I note that it truncates down.  My profile says "1 year 11 months" but the label says "1 year."

Comment: @doppelgreener So I went over the badges. Seems like the only one you're missing to get a perfect 40/40 is the [Steward badge](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges/95/steward).

Answer (score 5):

You can calculate it yourself, if you're so inclined. It's kind of fun.

**Candidate Score = Capped Reputation + Badge Count**

Where:

- **Capped Reputation** = Your reputation divided by 1000, rounded down. (Max 20)
- **Badge Count** = The number of badges you've earned from the following list. Earning the same badge twice counts as earning it once for this purpose. (Note there are 20 of them)

  - Civic Duty
  - Cleanup
  - Constituent
  - Convention
  - Copy Editor
  - Deputy
  - Electorate
  - Enthusiast
  - Explainer
  - Investor
  - Marshal
  - Organizer
  - Quorum
  - Refiner
  - Sportsmanship
  - Strunk & White
  - Tag Editor
  - Reviewer
  - Steward
  - Yearling